# Print Report in Landscape mode

Tags: reporting-services, landscape

I am using Reporting services,

I want to print out my report in landscape-format, and not in portrait-format, is there a property or any mode I have to change that I can create a landscape-formatted report?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to click outside of the body of the report (where the red box is)

[image: Where to Click]

This will bring up the Report Properties (my properties tab shows up on the right)

Here, you need to swap the height and width of the `PageSize' Field

[image: settings to change]

Then when SSRS tries to decide if this should be a portrait or a landscape it will know, without a doubt, that this is a landscape Report.

Comment: Additionally, in BIDS 2010, if you right-click outside the Body of the Report, select Page Setup, and under Paper Size, you can select Landscape and that will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the report property (right click on the background) and specify the paper size and the orientation there.

that is what it uses for printing

Comment: Do you know which properties a report has to have that it will change the format to landscape by itselfs? Ive tried it with 21 heigth and 29.7 width.. but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Where did u get this menue from? Mine isnt looking like that O.o

Comment: Into Visual Studio. Do a right click on the background (out of the report).

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Business Intelligence Studio 2012
The report settings from VS2010 is working well for setting paper size, orientation and margins. (As suggested by Malachi, but just giving VS screenshots) 
This can be accessible from VS menu as pictured below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't do that explicitly. 
I searched on the same question in context with SQL-2008. 
Result was that RS decides by itself, based on content.
But I can prove it by giving you some link.

**EDIT**

I searched especially in context of tablix report.

Comment: I thought that there is something like that because i havent found it in the Properties.. the next step is to evaluate how it decides by itselfs.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Sometimes you can have this set correctly and the printer simply ignores the settings and does whatever it's internal properties are set to. One work around to that is to print to PDF and then print the PDF document. Another is to manually change the printer properties before printing the document.